# RedHat - Rsync files using SSH authentication via HTTP proxy

Tags: proxy, redhat, rsync

What it says on the tin. I've got a firewall I don't control, an HTTP proxy I also don't control, and need to rsync files through the web proxy.

I have Googled this to death, but the only things that look like they might work require Corkscrew, which will be an unimaginable amount of paperwork to get approved for use.

Is there an easy way to route an rsync command through an HTTP proxy using ssh authentication?

Comment: If getting legitimate software approved sounds like a nightmare, this sounds like a good way to get fired or go to court.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best looking at HAProxy or Squid for HTTP proxying. Since I can't comment on your query, what is your intention here? If I could get a better understanding on the idea of this, I can help.

Comment: I have a system inside a firewall I do not control, and I need to upload a bunch of files to an external system using rsync. Due to firewall rules, I need to use an HTTP proxy that I also do not control.


Despite looking, the only reference to this I can find in the man page is RSYNC_PROXY, but that appears to only work when connecting to a dedicated rsync daemon, which I can't use because they are inherently not secure enough.


I can find no indication of how to send an rsync across the network using ssh authentication by way of an HTTP proxy.